# Replace ul bullets with a button

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to replace `ul` bullets with a button? I know you can change to images with CSS but if I wanted an actual element?

Comment: Darn okay... is there a way to replicate this though?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please explain the context.

Comment: @ATOzTOA A to-do list style thing. The buttons are the checkmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible as you asked, but you could, perhaps, emulate it:

```
<ul>
    <li><button>some button text</button>List-element text.</li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

li button {
    margin-right: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vWE7L/1/).

The success, or applicability, of this approach does, of course, depend entirely on your use-case which your question omits. With more detail, perhaps this answer can become more useful.

Comment: I'm making a to-do list style thing, so the button would serve as a checkbox/delete button. In JSfiddle, your solution works fine but directly in the browser (google chrome, coda preview) there is some extra indentation.

Comment: Just reduce the value of margin-right in the CSS for "li button".
    li button {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

Comment: Adjust the `margin-right` of the `button`, or specify `margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;` on the `li` elements. JS Fiddle uses a normalized CSS stylesheet to reduce the effects of varying browser defaults, which you may, or may not, have used. Try looking at [tag:css-reset] for some ideas on whether you should use one, or which you should use (if you're not already using one).

Answer (score 0):

No, with CSS you can style the bullets or have them omitted, and you can have generated content instead, but generated content introduces just a pseudo-element with some content, not a real button element for example.

If you need to have an `ul` element in markup (I wonder why), then you could use some JavaScript that injects `button` elements (and CSS that hides the bullets). But assuming that I guess your intentions correctly, why not use just a table with buttons in one column, associated content in another, or maybe just `div` elements with content starting with a `button` element?