# How to display selected file names before uploading multiple files in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How to use table instead of list for alignment. Also ones we click the cancel button the file list need to be deleted from list.

```
updateList = function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
            var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');

            output.innerHTML = '<ul style="list-style-type:none">';
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
                output.innerHTML += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '   <button>X</button></li> ';
            }
```

[output image for the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdqM9.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace ul bullets with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896455/replace-ul-bullets-with-a-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  updateList = function () {
             var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
             var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');var HTML = "<table>";
             for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i)
             {
                 HTML += "<tr><td>" + input.files.item(i).name + "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button>X</button></td></tr>";
             }
             HTML += "</table>";
             output.innerHTML = HTML;

         }
```